# Filter 3D python list using list or numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a python 3D list. Making it more clear, a list of list where each list is the four corner coordinate of a box. I have to filter all the boxes which are smaller than some given size.

Let us suppose this is the python list.

```
box = [[[4, 4], [4, 8], [8, 8], [8, 4]],
      [[8, 8], [8, 16], [16, 16], [16, 8]],
      [[20,16],[20,20],[24,20],[24,16]]
      ...
      ]
```

I have to filter all boxes with length and breadth less than or equal to 5.

```
filtered_box = [[[4, 4], [4, 8], [8, 8], [8, 4]],
                [[20,16],[20,20],[24,20],[24,16]]
               ...
               ]
```

This is my current code

```
filtered_box = []
for c in box:
    min_x, min_y = c[0]
    max_x, max_y = c[2]
    if max_x - min_x <= 5 & min_y - max_y <= 5:
        filtered_box.append(c)
```

This is working good but I need a more optimized solution. It can use numpy and convert back to python list or use the native python operations on list. I am using Python 3.

Comment: Have you attempted a numpy solution yet? If so, which part are you stuck on? This question is a little vague.

Comment: I iterated through the array in the same way. Can't find a vectorized solution.

Answer (score 1):

Solution with `numpy` may look like this:

```
filtered_array = array[
    (np.abs(array[:, 0, 0] - array[:, 3, 0]) < 5) &
    (np.abs(array[:, 0, 1] - array[:, 3, 1]) < 5), :, :]
```

where `array = np.array(box)`.

I guess this solution will be significantly faster than plain python if you have prepared data (numpy array). Transforming data from python list to numpy array will nullify any time gain.

Answer (score 0):

This list comprehension replaces your for-loop construct:

```py
import numpy as np

box = [
      [[4, 4], [4, 8], [8, 8], [8, 4]],
      [[8, 8], [8, 16], [16, 16], [16, 8]],
      [[20,16],[20,20],[24,20],[24,16]]
      ]

box = np.array(box) # convert to numpy array

# one-liner
filtered = [i for i in box if np.ptp(i[:,0]) <= 5 and np.ptp(i[:,1]) <= 5]

filtered = np.array(filtered) # if you want to convert to a numpy array
```